# how create pagination for table data and sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table, I want to create pagination for that, and sorting.

the pagination like:  prev<  page number of total record >next [ < 1 of 10 > ]

how do it?

this is my code:

```
<table id="datas">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Availability</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Do Krug</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$30.02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A Parolyn Chandler</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$52.94 ($26.47 &#215; 2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Inmy Sharp</td>
        <td>Out of Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$22.23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bulerholm</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$30.17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to display the data by pagination like  prevbtn  2 of 10  nextbtn.if i click the next btn it will dispaly the next 10 data, if i clike the prev btn it will display the prev 10 data.

Comment: StackOverflow is not *write-my-code-for-me.com*. You need to at least make an attempt and show what you tried :)

Comment: i found this fiddle online , you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Xugej/ or try jquery dataTable it has many options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used jQuery tablesorter with the tablesorter pager plug in.  You'll need to add these to your project, then you just need to add around 15 lines of code to this page.

Your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#datas").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    $("#datas").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
});
```

http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Your HTML:

```
<div id="pager" class="pager">
<form>
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
    <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option  value="40">40</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>

<table id="datas" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Item</th>
    <th scope="col">Availability</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Do Krug</td>
    <td>In Stock</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>$30.02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A Parolyn Chandler</td>
    <td>In Stock</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>$52.94 ($26.47 &#215; 2)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Inmy Sharp</td>
    <td>Out of Stock</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>$22.23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bulerholm</td>
    <td>In Stock</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>$30.17</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how to use that..send me js script

Comment: Use the two links I provided in the post -- download them and use them.  http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html#Download

Comment: wait ..i am checking.

Comment: send me by js fiddle.

Comment: pls help me..following files are included in my html files jquery.js, jquery.mousewheel.js, bootstrap.min.js, __jquery.tablesorter.js, jquery.tablesorter.pager.js so i got thios error:c is undefined
[Break On This Error] c.page = (c.totalPages-1);

Comment: You have data in the table?  I can only see that error getting displayed if there is no data either in the table, or no data being dynamically added to the table.  Your table data binding needs to finish before creating the tablesorter and tablesorterPager objects.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using jQuery for this. Previously, I've used a plug-in called DataTables. It's pretty straight-forward to use. [Here is a demo of the base functionality.](http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html)

It seems to fit the bill for what you're asking. It also allows for additional styling and customization, etc. Good luck!

n.i.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good tutorial for php pagination. Also, you need to make a small update to it, change all `mysql` reference to `mysqli`

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Thanks

Comment: no.pls understand what i am asking.i need pagination for table data.